# AngularJS Infinite Loop caused by Redirecting on Page Load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

I have the following code in the load function of my app:

```
  var token = window.localStorage.getItem("LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY");

  if (!token) {
    $window.location = 'login.html';
  }
  else {
    $window.location = 'index.html';
  }
```

I am trying to redirect the user based on whether or not they have logged in before by checking if the user has a token stored. By putting this in the load function of the app, it causes an infinite loop because when I redirect, it checks again and again..

So how is this typically handled? I haven't figured out a way to skip the login page if the user has a token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to a controller on the page (not the onload event):

```
if (!token) {
    if ($window.location === 'login.html') {
        return;
    }
    else 
     {
    $window.location = 'login.html';
     }
} else {
    $window.location = 'index.html';
}
```

This way if they are already on the login page it will not redirect them.

Comment: Easy enough. Surprised I didn't think of that. Quick question why do you have three "=" signs instead of two?

Comment: In javascript 3 "=" means it has to match the type of object and value. if you use 2 "=" it means it just has to match the value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness the mdn explains better than I can.

Comment: Ok thanks, for some reason the redirect loop is still happening.

Comment: Placing the code into a controller instead of onload fixes the problem, but this doesn't seem best practice

Comment: I wouldn't have any code in the onload anyway. if you need to test if someone is logged in, I would do it with an http intercepter for each request.